# AWS S3 bucket for public posting of data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, adobe-analytics, bucket

I am trying to get Adobe to post their clickstream analytics data - using Adobe Experience Amazon S3 File Delivery - to an AWS S3 bucket I created (called adobe). So I created an IAM user, assigned it to a group which has the following IAM policy, and I configured [Adobe S3 File Delivery](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/clickstream/datafeeds_configure.html) with the IAM user's access and secret keys.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListAndAlsoAllowGetBucketLocationRequiredForListBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootLevelListingOfCompanyBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::adobe",
                "arn:aws:s3:::adobe/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Wasn't sure what the bucket address was but tried:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/adobe/daily/
```

and each time Adobe come back with this error:

Exception caught: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketLocation operation: Access Denied

I tried web hosting this bucket and trying this bucket address instead:

```
http://adobe.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

... same error.

Using Cloudberry for S3, I checked the secret and access keys and it worked fine in terms of access to that bucket and sub folders. I didn't check using the CLI.

Any ideas / help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From the error message I see that Adobe is using APIs to perform S3 tasks and for APIs, S3 URL is not required. If Adobe give you any AWS account ID or role/user, you have to use S3 bucket policy as described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html . The IAM user is in your account, so the policy does not apply to Adobe (unless you have shared the access keys with them and which is not recommended).

Comment: Forgot to mention that for website hosting, you have to use S3 ACLs to grant access. Please make sure to grant Read permission only to the objects otherwise you will be opening the bucket to the world. Guide to set ACL: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-bucket-permissions.html

Comment: I presume you are referring to [Adobe Experience Amazon S3 File Delivery](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/clickstream/datafeeds_configure.html). In your above tests, how did you access the bucket? Did you use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with credentials for the IAM User you created, or did you just put the above links in a web browser? Please Edit your question to provide more detail about exactly how you tested access.

Comment: Adobe S3 File Delivery requires you to give them 4 things: a bucket name ('adobe'), an access key, a secret key, and a folder name (such as 'clickstream').

Answer (score 0):

@jarmod - that was the answer - adding a bucket name rather than bucket address made it work. Thanks

Thanks to everyone else.